# How to add custom checkbox in column in react material table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, material-table

Hi i am using material table in react project. I want to add a checkbox in my table cell.
For example in Birth year colume in place of 1987. How to achieve that?

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-5h51b?file=/demo.js:701-911

[image]

```
<MaterialTable
      title="Editable Example"
      columns={state.columns}
      data={state.data}
      options={{
        selection: true
      }}
      editable={{
       //Edit Code here
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer... In column just add type:'boolean'.
For eg,

```
    {
      title: "Unit",
      field: "unit",
      type: 'boolean',
      
    },
```